# TDS overwrites existing model

Tags: tds

I am new to TDS.
I have a template which has a ContentList field of type TreeList. This field is allowed to select any page template. When I map this changes in TDS(Visual Studio) the tds generates a model automatically for this field like,

**object ContentList{get;set;}** but I want this as ***IEnumerable(IMytmeplate) ContentList{get;set;}***

Whenever I make changes in CMS and merge in code this is getting overwritten. Is there any way to achieve the desired result? Similarly I have a date picker field and I want it to be nullable. Whenever I make changes to content in CMS and merge in code these fields are getting overwritten and I need to make the changes manually.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is available OTTB in TDS, to accomplish this you can follow below steps:

1. Select `ContentList` field item and right click and select `Properties`

[image]
2. Go to `Custom Data` field and type

```
type=IEnumerable<Namespace.IMytmeplate>
```

[image]

3. Again sync, it will work

Comment: Thanks Swati and Mark. I was able to achieve the desired result.